# how to handle cross-domain testing in selenium

Tags: selenium

How to handle cross-domain functionality in selenium.can any one explain me plz?

For ex: need to open Google.com and gmail, Using same selenium session object, I was seeing permission denied error , i tried with *iehta, Proxy injection mode as well it didn't work can you help me out..

Comment: Are you using Selenium IDE or RC?

Answer (score 1):

I found this anwer on [stackexchange.com](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-the-base-url-be-changed-in-the-same-browser-session-using-selenium-rc):

> You should be able to do so while using browsers with elevated
>   security privileges like *chrome for firefox. So you could just do
>
> ```
> selenium.open("newURL");
> ```
>
> in your test. Problem of changing URL is, it change in domain and
>   normal Selenium browser mode is restricted by Java Script's Same
>   Origin Policy, as I mentioned above browsers with elevated security
>   privileges should get you going.
>
> I suppose this is the point where you are trying to load another URL
>   in same selenium session -
>
> ```
> sel.open("www.google.com");
> sel.waitForPageToLoad(stimeout);
> ```
>
> First - **don't use waitForPageToLoad**, open api takes care of it.
>   Now if sel.open does not work then you should definitely encounter
>   error. Don't keep you method in try catch block and see the error you
>   encounter....
>
> [1](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-the-base-url-be-changed-in-the-same-browser-session-using-selenium-rc):
>   https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-the-base-url-be-changed-in-the-same-browser-session-using-selenium-rc

Answer (score 0):

If can't open two different domains with one selenium object, try using a different object for each domain (e.g. an object called seleniumGoogle and an object calledseleniumGmail).